# Find files created by program

Tags: file

Is there an app out there that lets you see what files were created by a program? Basically I need to figure out where a lock file for a Java program is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Activity Monitor. Left-click on the Java app > Information > Open Files and Ports.

You get list of all opened files for this application.